# kubenetes deployment expose pods on a port

Tags: kubernetes

My goal is to expose all my ports under one service.

My pod contains a containerised app that runs under port 80.

This is my attempt to create the deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: name: my-deployment
spec:
    replicas: 5
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: myapp
    template:
        metadata:
            name: my-pod
            labels:
                app: myapp
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: httd
                  image: httpd
                  imagePullPolicy: Always
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 80
```

However, I am getting error:

```
error: error parsing deployment.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 3: mapping values are not allowed in this context
```

#### Notes:

- If I remove the ports section, the deployment will be created successfully but then the service (that I have it in another file and that I can share if needed), would be able to link a port on the node to a port in the pod because the pod doesn't expose any port (again it just the the container running on a port)
- I went through [this page](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/), and it does say to use the containerPort so I don't know what I missed

#### Update

The error was in my deployment file: and after fixing it, I could create both the deployment and the service, but the service is still not exposed on the node. Here is my service definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: my-service
spec:
    selector:
            app: front-end
    ports:
        - port: 77
          targetPort: 80
          nodePort: 32766
    type: NodePort
```

As you can see, I am mapping the port 80 in the pod to port 32766 on the node, and when calling: localhost:32766 it returns 404

What did I miss?

#### Update

This is what the browser shows:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the error is not due to the metadata (line 3 ) : metadata: name: my-deployment. the "name" should be on the next line I think

Comment: @XavierFRANCOIS yes indeed that was the error. I fixed it but the service still not working. I updated the question, could you have a look?

Comment: If you get a 404 a server is returning it. If there was nothing there you would get a connection failure.

Answer (score 1):

> when calling: localhost:32766 it returns 404

this means that the app is actually responding to the request. But you sent the request for an **URL** that the app has not implemented. `404 Not Found` is an Http status code that web servers respond when they don't have a path for the requested URL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think i was mistaken, it is not 404. as shown in my updated question

Comment: If you have a different question, it is better to ask a new question, since this question already has answers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in your selector section of service.yaml file
try this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: my-service
spec:
    selector:
            app: myapp
    ports:
        - port: 77
          targetPort: 80
          nodePort: 32766
    type: NodePort
```

Comment: I see, I changed that but didn't help, still the same error

Comment: pls share o/p of kubectl get deployment my-deployment -o yaml and kubectl get svc my-service -o yaml

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @shubam_asati posted, your service yaml has `port: 77` and `targetPort: 80`. But your deployment container is port is `80`. Change `port` value to the same value as `targetPort` (ie `80`) and you should be able to connect to the app at `localhost:<nodePort>`.